# cleaning same values in array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to clear same values in array.
For example so be my array:

```
array(0=>"1",1=>"1",2=>"3",3=>"1",4=>"6");
```

I want ot get as:

```
array(0=>"1",1=>"3",2=>"6");
```

How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$input = array(0=>"1",1=>"1",2=>"3",3=>"1",4=>"6");
$result = array_values(array_unique($input));
print_r($result);
?>
```

[array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [2] => 3
    [4] => 6
)
```

[array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) with [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 6
)
```

Answer (score 1):

With a combination of [`array_unique` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) and [`array_values` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php):

```
$array = array_values(array_unique($array));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want the `array_unique()` function ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php ):

```
$arr = array_unique(array(0 => '1', 1 => '1', 2 => '2'));
```

will return:

```
array(0=> '1', 2 => '2')
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use [array_slice](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) for this purpose. Then edit the keys' values manually

Edit: `To remove a key/value pair, call the unset() function on it.` from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) under *Creating/modifying with square bracket syntax* section.